# How to access an attribute defined in __init__() in the methods decorated with @classmethod?

Tags: python, class

I am trying to access cls.dates in both the methods defined in the class decorated with `@classmethod`s. But below code gives me an error `Database has no attribute dates`. I need help to access it in the methods.

```
class Database:
""" class that works with data storage and retrieval. """

    def __init__(cls, file='D:\\vscode\\Python\\data.db'):
        # initialise database with a file-name

        cls.dates = {
            1:31,
            2:28,
            3:31,
            4:30,
            5:31,
            6:30,
            7:31,
            8:31,
            9:30,
            10:31,
            11:30,
            12:31
        }

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, data):
        connection = sqlite3.connect('D:\\vscode\\Python\\data.db')
        c = connection.cursor()
        c.execute('INSERT INTO mydata (accuracy, efficiency, day, month) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);', (data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]))
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, date):
        (_day, _month) = tuple(map(int, date.split('-')))

        #calculate low-expressions
        if _day <= 3:
            low_month = _month-1
            low_day = cls.dates[low_month]-(3-_day)
        else:
            low_month = _month
            low_day = _day-3

        #calculate high-expression
        if _day > cls.dates[_month]-3:
            high_month = _month+1
            high_day = _day - cls.dates[_month] + 3
        else:
            high_month = _month
            high_day = _day + 3

        # establish connection and retrive the data
        connection = sqlite3.connect('D:\\vscode\\Python\\data.db')
        c = connection.cursor()
        c.execute('SELECT accuracy, efficiency, day, month FROM mydata WHERE day BETWEEN (?) AND (?) AND month BETWEEN (?) and (?);',(low_day, high_day, low_month, high_month))
        to_plot = c.fetchall()
        connection.close()

        # return the data
        return to_plot
```

I cannot access the dates attribute of the `Database` class from any method.

Comment: The `dates` attribute is set on *instances*, not the class. Why are the other methods class methods?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It sounds like you've misunderstood the idea of what a classmethod is.

Comment: I don't know how else to put it. Why did you decide to make get and add class methods when they need access to an attribute that's set on the instance, or why did you decide to make dates an instance attribute when it's needed by class methods?

Comment: so how should i not make it an Instance attribute

Comment: You can access `class` attributes by prefixing them with  the classname i.e.`Database.` or `self.` in methods.

Comment: Plus, naming the first argument `cls` in `__init__` suggests that you might not have realized the difference between a class and an instance.

Comment: Now i understand you! dates will only be create when the class is instantiated as an object

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: I think the problem is the OP doesn't understand classes vs instances of them.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Please repeat your tutorials or other references to understand class vs instance.  Stack Overflow is not a tutorial forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between a class and an object.  An object is an instance of a class.  You can have many objects (instances) of the same class An object has all of the class's data and methods, but also it's own data.

classmethods run on the class.  Instance methods run on the object.  A classmethod can't access data from an object of the class because (among other reasons) there can be many objects of that class.

You have two options:

1. Make the classmethods instance methods (delete the `@classmethod` decorator).  Then, they are methods on the object and can access object level data.
2. Move the data you want to be accessible by the classmethods to the class (put it outside the init function).

Option 1:

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dates = {...}
    
    def add(self, data):
        logic(self.dates)

database = Database()
database.add(...)
```

Option 2:

```
class Database:
    dates = {...}
    
    @classmethod
    def add(cls, data):
        logic(cls.dates)

Database.add(...)
```

BTW, it is convention to refer to the first parameter of classmethods as `cls` and the first parameter of instance methods as `self` to avoid this very confusion.

Comment: I already did delete @classmethod and then used object to do stuff. 2 options is what i was looking for. thank you

Comment: with option 2 can i instantiate an object using class like option 2

Comment: I dont need to but is it possible

Comment: @ShoaibWani I added sample usage to the examples.  You can create an instance of the class in example 2, but if there is no data or methods on the instance, there is no reason to.

Comment: @ShoaibWani Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem.